# datatables empty table error

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a piece of code where I use the datatables plugin.

The table structure looks like this:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
        <th>col4</th>
        <th>col5</th>
        <th>col6</th>
        <th>col7</th>
        <th>col8</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

but notice that in the initialization code I am hiding the last four columns.

In my code, I do the following:

```
if($data->responseCode < 400)
{
    echo HTML Table
}
```

that works

```
else
{
    echo '<tr><td colspan=4><h1 class="error">'.$data->errorMsg.'</h1></td></tr>';
}
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

"DataTables warning (table id = 'DataTables_Table_0'): Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row 0"

here is the dataables code:

```
var oTable = $('.table1').DataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 100,
    "aaSortingFixed": [[0,'desc']],
    "aaSorting": [ [0,'asc'] ],
    "aoColumnDefs": [
          { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ 4,5,6,7 ] },
          { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7] },
          { "bSearchable": true, "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
        ]
});
```

Does anybody know what would be causing that? I thought maybe it was the colspan but when I remove that, the problem still exists. The weird thing is that I use this on another page and it seems to handle an empty result set just fine.

Not sure if this helps but after playing a little I managed to get the following error to show up in firebug:

"TypeError: nTd is undefined"

Answer (score 6):

If you use datatables often, then this is the common error that you will get. The reason is that the data format that you use to create the data table can't match the table columns, for example you have 4 columns while the source data just can provides 3 columns. You can post the data format and the table structure, let me check the further issue.

Comment: I addded in the table head structure. but see that according to the initialization code I am trying to hide the last four columns.

Comment: do you think that that the colspan would have want to do with it?

Comment: I think you can have a try, I didn't use it with this way.

Comment: I tried to remove the colspan and that did not do anything, I tried to lower the span but that didnt help either. This is really an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this with a small logic, check for the empty records and set table class dynamically for every data table.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered <?php echo !empty($rows) ? 'data-table-display-class' : ''; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because dataTable check the matched total of "column" in header & body table

```
else
    {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$data->errorMsg.'</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              </tr>';
    }
```

It will shows like empty row and with errorMsg in the first column of your row.

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` statement do not include `table` HTML start tag, maybe this is the problem, you echo out only a row.
Try

```
else
{
    echo '<table id="table_id" class="table1"><tr><td colspan=4><h1 class="error">'.$data->errorMsg.'</h1></td></tr></table>';
}
```

Comment: All the table and table head tags are done above, the header fields are still in place. This condition is only for the creation of the table body.